# Using array as key in unordered_set

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, hash, unordered-set

I want to use an **unordered_set** having as key an *unsigned long long**, but I want to implement the **hash** and the **equal_to** using the values stored. For instance:

```
int size = 4;
typedef unsigned long long verylong;
verylong* x = new verylong[size];
// calc hash and equal using x[0]..x[3]
```

The easy method is to use a wrapper.

```
class VeryLong {
verylong* array;
int arraySize;
...
bool operator==(const VeryLong& x) { // use the array and arraySize }
...
};
namespace std {

template <>
class hash<VeryLong>
{
    std::size_t operator()(const VeryLong& v) const
    {

     // Compute hash values for array (using murmur, maybe)
     //...
    }
};
```

But I don't want to use a wrapper due to memory consumption. I want something like:

```
std::unordered_set<verylong*,MyHash,MyEqual> set;
```

The problem is to implement **MyHash** and **MyEqual**, because the arraySize is not constant (I only know arraySize in execution time).

I tried this:

```
typedef struct MyHash
{
    int arraySize;
    MyHash(int size) : arraySize(arraySize) {}
    long operator() (const verylong* const k) const { return hash(k,size); }
} MyHash;
```

But I cannot use this, because **MyHash** is not  *constexpr*.

Is what I want possible to do?

EDIT: If I try using the MyHash implemented above:

```
int size;
// someone sets size a positive value 
std::unordered_set<verylong*,MyHash(size),MyEqual> set;
```

The following error occurs:

**error: temporary of non-literal type 'MyHash' in a constant expression std::unordered_set< verylong*, MyHash(size), MyEquals> set;**

Comment: What *memory consumption* are you worried about with the wrapper? All you're doing is storing a pointer and the length of the array, which you'll need to store *somewhere* in any case. And how did you come up with the requirement that the hasher needs to be `constexpr`?

Comment: I will have thousands (millions) of these *verylong* allocated in memory. So, the memory cost is : 8 bytes from wrapper, 8 bytes from pointer + 8*size bytes for the content + 4 bytes for int + padding. The overhead is 12 bytes, sometimes to store only one 64 bit value. This is a cost I don't want to have. About the constexpr, I added more info in my question.

Comment: Are all of your `verylong` going to have the same size?

Comment: OK, I didn't understand at first that all your arrays were going to be of the same length, in which case you can get away with storing the length once each hash and equal comparator instances, instead of along with every set element.

Comment: Mark Ransom Unfortunately no. In most cases they will have the same size, but in some cases, not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second template argument to `std::unordered_set<>` should be `MyHash` rather than `MyHash(size)`, as a *type* is expected here rather than an object. Change your `set` declaration to:

```
std::unordered_set<verylong*, MyHash, MyEqual> set(bucket_count, MyHash(size));
```

Presumably `MyEqual` will need a similar argument for `size`, in which case do:

```
std::unordered_set<verylong*, MyHash, MyEqual> set(bucket_count, MyHash(size), MyEqual(size));
```

For `bucket_count`, use a guesstimate of how many elements will be in your set.

As a side note, don't `typedef` your `struct`s that way – that's a hideous C-ism that serves no purpose in C++.

Comment: Thanks ildjam, It works like a charm.
My bad about the typedef. I was trying some snippets for hash and I didn't see that.
+1 for the answer and a virtual +1 for the "guesstimate".

Comment: @MaylerMartins I don't get it, how does this solution work for you? You've said in the comments below the question that the array lengths can differ. ildjarn's solution assumes the same length for every array in the set.

Comment: Sorry @Praetorian, I think I was not clear. 
If I have 2 sets in my code, one would contain pointers with size, for instance, 2; and the other would contain pointers with size 3. For me this is fine.

When I commented I was thinking the all arrays during execution would have fixed size. 
If I have a set of verylong with size 1 and size 2, if the size passed in constructor is 2,  probably I would have a segmentation fault.

Comment: @MaylerMartins : To be clear, every element in a given set has the same size, that size just isn't known at compile-time, correct?

Comment: @ildjarn, yes. For each set, all elements have the same size.

Comment: @MaylerMartins : Okay, then all is well. :-]